# How to fix too many open files error when aggregating billions of records

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

I got the following error

`opening file "/workspace/mongo/data/_tmp/extsort.63355": errno:24 Too many open files`

How could I fix this error ?

Because the opened files is alreaday 63355 ?

```
2015-05-02T08:01:40.490+0000 I COMMAND  [conn1] command sandbox.$cmd command: listCollections { listCollections: 1.0 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:411 locks:{} 169ms
2015-05-02T15:01:02.060+0000 I -        [conn2] Assertion: 16818:error opening file "/workspace/mongo/data/_tmp/extsort.63355": errno:24 Too many open files
2015-05-02T15:01:02.235+0000 I CONTROL  [conn2] 
 0xf4d299 0xeeda71 0xed2d3f 0xed2dec 0xb3f453 0xb3c88c 0xb3d2dd 0xb3dfe2 0xb499c5 0xb49136 0xb7e3e6 0x987165 0x9d8b04 0x9d9aed 0x9da7fb 0xb9e956 0xab4d20 0x80e75d 0xf00e6b 0x7fe38e8b4182 0x7fe38d37c47d
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"400000","o":"B4D299"},{"b":"400000","o":"AEDA71"},{"b":"400000","o":"AD2D3F"},{"b":"400000","o":"AD2DEC"},{"b":"400000","o":"73F453"},{"b":"400000","o":"73C88C"},{"b":"400000","o":"73D2DD"},{"b":"400000","o":"73DFE2"},{"b":"400000","o":"7499C5"},{"b":"400000","o":"749136"},{"b":"400000","o":"77E3E6"},{"b":"400000","o":"587165"},{"b":"400000","o":"5D8B04"},{"b":"400000","o":"5D9AED"},{"b":"400000","o":"5DA7FB"},{"b":"400000","o":"79E956"},{"b":"400000","o":"6B4D20"},{"b":"400000","o":"40E75D"},{"b":"400000","o":"B00E6B"},{"b":"7FE38E8AC000","o":"8182"},{"b":"7FE38D282000","o":"FA47D"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.0.1", "gitVersion" : "534b5a3f9d10f00cd27737fbcd951032248b5952", "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "3.13.0-44-generic", "version" : "#73-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 00:22:43 UTC 2014", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "elfType" : 2, "b" : "400000", "buildId" : "C35E766AD226FC0C16CB0C3885EC3B59E288A3F2" }, { "b" : "7FFF448FE000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9D77366C6409A9EA266179080FA7C779EEA8A958" }, { "b" : "7FE38E8AC000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9318E8AF0BFBE444731BB0461202EF57F7C39542" }, { "b" : "7FE38E64E000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "FF43D0947510134A8A494063A3C1CF3CEBB27791" }, { "b" : "7FE38E273000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B927879B878D90DD9FF4B15B00E7799AA8E0272F" }, { "b" : "7FE38E06B000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "92FCF41EFE012D6186E31A59AD05BDBB487769AB" }, { "b" : "7FE38DE67000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C1AE4CB7195D337A77A3C689051DABAA3980CA0C" }, { "b" : "7FE38DB63000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "19EFDDAB11B3BF5C71570078C59F91CF6592CE9E" }, { "b" : "7FE38D85D000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1D76B71E905CB867B27CEF230FCB20F01A3178F5" }, { "b" : "7FE38D647000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8D0AA71411580EE6C08809695C3984769F25725B" }, { "b" : "7FE38D282000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "30C94DC66A1FE95180C3D68D2B89E576D5AE213C" }, { "b" : "7FE38EACA000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9F00581AB3C73E3AEA35995A0C50D24D59A01D47" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x29) [0xf4d299]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0xE1) [0xeeda71]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo11msgassertedEiPKc+0xAF) [0xed2d3f]
 mongod(+0xAD2DEC) [0xed2dec]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo16SortedFileWriterINS_5ValueES1_EC1ERKNS_11SortOptionsERKSt4pairINS1_25SorterDeserializeSettingsES7_E+0x5D3) [0xb3f453]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19DocumentSourceGroup5spillEv+0x1BC) [0xb3c88c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19DocumentSourceGroup8populateEv+0x46D) [0xb3d2dd]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo19DocumentSourceGroup7getNextEv+0x292) [0xb3dfe2]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo21DocumentSourceProject7getNextEv+0x45) [0xb499c5]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo17DocumentSourceOut7getNextEv+0xD6) [0xb49136]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8Pipeline3runERNS_14BSONObjBuilderE+0xA6) [0xb7e3e6]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15PipelineCommand3runEPNS_16OperationContextERKSsRNS_7BSONObjEiRSsRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0x7A5) [0x987165]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12_execCommandEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_7CommandERKSsRNS_7BSONObjEiRSsRNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0x34) [0x9d8b04]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo7Command11execCommandEPNS_16OperationContextEPS0_iPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEb+0xC7D) [0x9d9aed]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo12_runCommandsEPNS_16OperationContextEPKcRNS_7BSONObjERNS_11_BufBuilderINS_16TrivialAllocatorEEERNS_14BSONObjBuilderEbi+0x28B) [0x9da7fb]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8runQueryEPNS_16OperationContextERNS_7MessageERNS_12QueryMessageERKNS_15NamespaceStringERNS_5CurOpES3_+0x746) [0xb9e956]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo16assembleResponseEPNS_16OperationContextERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_11HostAndPortE+0xB10) [0xab4d20]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo16MyMessageHandler7processERNS_7MessageEPNS_21AbstractMessagingPortEPNS_9LastErrorE+0xDD) [0x80e75d]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo17PortMessageServer17handleIncomingMsgEPv+0x34B) [0xf00e6b]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x8182) [0x7fe38e8b4182]
 libc.so.6(clone+0x6D) [0x7fe38d37c47d]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
2015-05-02T15:02:07.753+0000 I COMMAND  [conn2] CMD: drop sandbox.tmp.agg_out.1
```

## UPDATE

I typed `ulimit -n unlimited` on the console,

and modified the `/etc/security/limits.conf` with the following setting

```
* soft nofile unlimited
* hard nofile unlimited
* soft nproc unlimited
* hard nproc unlimited
```

check it by **ulimit -a**

```
health# ulimit -a
-t: cpu time (seconds)              unlimited
-f: file size (blocks)              unlimited
-d: data seg size (kbytes)          unlimited
-s: stack size (kbytes)             8192
-c: core file size (blocks)         0
-m: resident set size (kbytes)      unlimited
-u: processes                       unlimited
-n: file descriptors                4096
-l: locked-in-memory size (kbytes)  64
-v: address space (kbytes)          unlimited
-x: file locks                      unlimited
-i: pending signals                 31538
-q: bytes in POSIX msg queues       819200
-e: max nice                        0
-r: max rt priority                 0
-N 15:                              unlimited
health# ulimit -Sn
4096
health# ulimit -Hn
4096
```

Is my system's setting alreday unlimited on open files ?

Answer (score 4):

There is no clean answer for this as you are doing something very heavy stuff but workaround is available

`ulimit` is command in unix/linux which allows to set system limits for all properties.

in your case you need to increase max. no. of open files count or make it unlimited on safer side (it is also recommended by MongoDB)

```
ulimit -n <large value in your case 1000000>

or 

sysctl -w fs.file-max=1000000

and

/etc/security/limits.conf or /etc/sysctl.conf:
change 

fs.file-max = 1000000
```

Comment: Hi Thank you ,Is it possible to set to unlimited ? and how to ensure the setting is changed ?

Comment: unfortunately we cannot set it to unlimited (even root). but you can provide max no as I have provided in ans. you can check it using ulimit -a

Comment: Update  shows that your limit is 4096 and not 65336. you can modify it and check it again

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, so `ulimit -a` will show me all the max number for each setting , right ?

Answer (score 3):

I found that it was necessary to change the system-wide settings (using `ulimit` as suggested Nachiket Kate; another great description for Ubuntu may be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162229/how-do-i-increase-the-open-files-limit-for-a-non-root-user)) as well as the mongodb settings (as documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/#linux-distributions-using-systemd)).

For the sake of explanation, I'll summarize the commands I performed to get a handle on things (I'll reference the links again where they belong in the discussion).

Determine if the maximum number of file descriptors as enforced by the kernel are sufficient (the amount was sufficient)?

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
6569231
```

In my case this was not the problem. Checking the `ulimit` settings for the mongodb user revealed what the number of file descriptors were a paltry 1024:

```
$ sudo -H -u mongodb bash -c 'ulimit -a'
...
open files                      (-n) 1024
...
```

These values could be changed for all users by increasing the soft (user can modify them) and hard limits (I set mine quite high):

```
$ sudo su
$ echo -e "* hard\tnofile\t1000000\n* soft\tnofile\t990000" >> /etc/security/limits.conf
```

This may also be done on a user basis by replacing the `*` with the username. Although this worked on per-user basis, restarting the mongo daemon resulted in the number of file descriptors returning to 1024. It was necessary to follow the advice [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/162230) regarding the pam session:

```
$ for file in /etc/pam.d/common-session*; do 
      echo 'session required pam_limits.so' >> $file
  done
```

To test that the settings have been applied, I created a wee python script (placed in `/tmp/file_descriptor_test.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
n=990000

fd_list=list()
for i in range(1,n):
    fd_list.append(open('/tmp/__%08d' % (i), 'w'))

print 'opened %d fds' % n
```

Running this as the mongodb user revealed that all was well system-wise:

```
sudo -H -u mongodb bash -c '/tmp/file_descriptor_test.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/fd.py", line 8, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/tmp/__00989998'
```

The files in `/tmp/` may be deleted using

```
sudo find -type f -name '__*' -delete
```

as you'll be unable to list them properly (so `rm` doesn't work).

However, when running the offending mongo process, I still encountered the same `Too many open files` error. This led me to believe that the problem also lay with mongo (and led me, finally and embarrassingly to the excellent [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/#linux-distributions-using-systemd). Editing the `etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mongodb-01.service` and adding the following lines beneath `[Service]` directive

```
# (file size)
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# (cpu time)
LimitCPU=infinity
# (virtual memory size)
LimitAS=infinity
# (open files)
LimitNOFILE=990000
# (processes/threads)
LimitNPROC=495000
```

finally resolved the issue (remember to restart systemctl with `sudo systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart mongodb-01.service`). You can monitor the progress of the mongo process (mine was a temporary space hungry aggregate) via

```
$ while true; do echo $(find /var/lib/mongodb_01/_tmp/ | wc -l); sleep 1; done
```